# ¿Que hago con las entidades relacionadas si hago un soft reset en un mantenedor de ellas?

Tags: c#, poo, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Estoy trabajando en clases abstractas que me permitan ahorrar codigo, exactamente de servicios (Vease, implementar el crud automaticamente, o solo la funcion de lectura), a la par que ofrezco funciones para obtener la ultima fecha de actualizacion, de creacion y la posibilidad de hace un soft delete, mediante el campo Active

Exactamente para hacer los test hice un modelado de datos basico, constando de dos tablas en relacion "1 a muchos". Mostrare fotos del codigo (Es C#, con EntityFramework Core)

Un Primary model - Muchos Mainteiner

```cs
public class PrimaryModel : AbstractModel<int>, IDomainOf<PrimaryModelDTO>
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(128, MinimumLength = 5)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public int MainteinerId { get; set; }

    public Mainteiner MainteinerNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class Mainteiner : AbstractModel<int>
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(128, MinimumLength = 5)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<PrimaryModel> PrimaryModelNavigations { get; set; }
}
```

Muestro el codigo de AbstractModel, para mostrar lo que tiene

```
public abstract class AbstractModel<TKey> : IAbstractModel<TKey>
{
    [Required]
    public TKey Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public bool? Active { get; set; } = true;

    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

Exactamente en el servicio abstracto (Que implementa el CRUD), tengo la funcion delete, que hace el soft delete que mencione, muestro codigo

```
public virtual void Delete(TKey key)
{
    TEntity entity = Context
        .Set<TEntity>()
        .Find(key);

    if (entity == null || entity.Active.Value)
        throw new EntityNotFoundException();

    entity.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
    entity.Active = !entity.Active;

    Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Supongamos que tengo dos entidades de Mainteiner, una activa (Id 1) y otra que no (Id 2, La no activa nunca es leida nunca desde las funciones read que estan en mis servicios abstractos), y tengo tambien otras dos entidades de Primary Model que ambas estan activas (Id 1 y 2), Primary Model de Id 1, hace referencia a Mainteiner de Id 1 (Que esta activo) y Primary Model de Id 2, hace referencia a Mainteiner de ID 2 (Que no esta activo)

Mi duda va en sentido de... ¿Que hago con las entidad de Primary Model que hace referencia a un Mainteiner no activo? ¿No la muestro?

En ese caso, cada vez que cambio el estado de un mainteiner a no activo, tendria que cambiar todas las referencias que tenga dicha entidad a sus relaciones, desactivandolas (Esto no aplica si activo una entidad Mainteiner, tendria que activar cada una de las relaciones manualmente)

¿Alguna recomendación de que hago en este procedimiento?

En caso de que necesiten mas contexto, les dare el git del codigo
[Git](https://github.com/HernanFAR/QuestionAnswerBlazor/tree/develop/Logic/Service/AbstractServices), para que puedan verlo a detalle

Comment: Te recomiendo editar tu pregunta y colocar el código como texto, no es buena practica ponerlo en imagen, nos dificultas el trabajo.

Comment: Inmediatamente, camarada :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen dia

Encontre la solucion en este caso, al final opte porque si la entidad es obligatoria (El Id de la relacion no es nulo), se tendra el comportamiento default de EntityFramework, arroja un InvalidOperationException

Sin embargo, si es una relacion opcional, se hace un soft delete con el resto de entidades relacionadas ¿Como se hizo esto? Simple.

```
protected virtual void HandleChangedEntities(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (EntityEntry entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
        switch (entry.State)
        {
            case EntityState.Added:
                {
                    if (entry.CurrentValues.Properties.Any(e => e.Name == "Active"))
                    {
                        entry.CurrentValues["Active"] = true;
                    }

                    break;
                }

            case EntityState.Modified:
                {
                    if (entry.CurrentValues.Properties.Any(e => e.Name == "Active"))
                    {
                        entry.CurrentValues["Active"] = true;
                    }

                    break;
                }

            case EntityState.Deleted:
                {
                    if (entry.CurrentValues.Properties.Any(e => e.Name == "Active"))
                    {
                        entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                        entry.CurrentValues["Active"] = false;

                        foreach (NavigationEntry navigationEntry in entry.Navigations.Where(n => !((INavigation)n.Metadata).IsOnDependent))
                        {
                            if (navigationEntry is CollectionEntry collectionEntry)
                            {
                                if (collectionEntry.CurrentValue == null)
                                    continue;

                                foreach (object dependentEntry in collectionEntry.CurrentValue)
                                {
                                    HandleDependent(Entry(dependentEntry));
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (navigationEntry.CurrentValue == null)
                                    continue;

                                HandleDependent(Entry(navigationEntry.CurrentValue));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                }
        }
    }
}

protected virtual void HandleDependent(EntityEntry entry)
{
    if (entry.CurrentValues.Properties.Any(e => e.Name == "Active"))
        entry.CurrentValues["Active"] = false;
}
```

Este codigo lo que hace es que se ejecuta antes de hacer el SaveChanges, mediante la propiedad SavingChanges, que puede contener funciones que se ejecutan antes del guardar los cambios en la base de datos. El codigo para agregarlo al SavingChanges es este (Yo lo deje en el constructor)

```cs
public TestContext(DbContextOptions options) :
    base(options) 
{
    SavingChanges += HandleChangedEntities;
}
```

Ahora, cada vez que se ejecuta el SaveChanges y detecta que una entidad va a borrase y tiene el atributo de activo, primero le cambio el estado a modificado y le pone el campo activo en falso

```
entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
entry.CurrentValues["Active"] = false;
```

Luego, verifica sus relaciones en las que es el padre (Sea de 1 a N o de 1 a 1)

```
foreach (NavigationEntry navigationEntry in entry.Navigations.Where(n => !((INavigation)n.Metadata).IsOnDependent)) 
{
    [Codigo ...]
}
```

Si tiene una relacion de 1 a N (Que en EntityFramework se expresa con una colección (Array, List, etc) verifica que tenga valores (Por eso el primer if null, ya que si no tiene "hijos", este es nulo) y si los tiene, va uno por uno a cambiarles el Activo a false, esto ultimo mediante HandleDependent

```
if (navigationEntry is CollectionEntry collectionEntry)
{
    if (collectionEntry.CurrentValue == null)
        continue;

    foreach (object dependentEntry in collectionEntry.CurrentValue)
    {
        HandleDependent(Entry(dependentEntry));
    }
}
```

Codigo de handleDependent

```
protected virtual void HandleDependent(EntityEntry entry)
{
    if (entry.CurrentValues.Properties.Any(e => e.Name == "Active"))
        entry.CurrentValues["Active"] = false;
}
```

Si es una relacion 1 a 1 (EntityFramwork las llama de "Referencia"), primeramente verifica si es nula (Si no hay datos ingresados en esa relacion) y si no lo es, la desactiva

```
else
{
    if (navigationEntry.CurrentValue == null)
        continue;

    HandleDependent(Entry(navigationEntry.CurrentValue));
}
```

Ahora, estoy aun tiene problemas, ya que no se que tan bueno es en terminos de performance, no conozco mucho de entityFramework, asi que no se si cuando verifico sus valores asi, los llamo en memoria o solo son los usados para formar el Query (Que es lo correcto)

Tambien, a lo mejor actualmente no es el codigo mas ordenado, sin embargo, es funcional. Si ven alguna refactorizacion posible para que sea mas elegante, por favor ¡mencionenla!, la hare con muchisimo gusto